# Optimal synthesis of crank–rocker linkages

Tags: optimization

I need help programming a script, in MATLAB, that for assigned values compute the optimal transmission angle of a [crank-rocker mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-bar_linkage#Classification).

The parameters are:

- $L$: crank's angle of oscillation, for example from -20° to 150°
- $m$: rocker's angle of oscillation, it's a fixed value.
- $t$:  $\tan(L/2)$
- $u$: $\tan((L-m)/2)$
- $v$: $\tan(m/2)$

There is a condition on $L$, $L<(90+(m/2))$

The equation is a cubic:

$$Q^3 + 2Q^2 - t^2 Q- \frac{t^2(1+t^2)}{u^2}$$

where $Q=t^2/x^2$.

The roots of $Q$ must be real and positive.
$x$ is the variable and it should satisfy the following inequalities:
$x^2 \geq 1$ and $x^2 \leq u^2 t^2$.

Now the lengths of the 4-bar are
\begin{align}
a &= \sqrt{\frac{v^2}{1 + v^2}}\cr
b &= \sqrt{\frac{x^2 v^2}{1 + v^2}}\cr
c &= \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + t^2}{1 + t^2}}\cr
d &= \sqrt{\frac{u^2 + x^2}{1 + u^2}}
\end{align}

I solve the equation for $Q$ then calculate $x$. Now the transmission angle (max and min) depends on $a(x)$, $b(x)$, $c(x)$ and $d(x)$. I have a different transmission angle (max and min) for all the different values of crank's angle of oscillation. For example as, Istated previously from $-20$ to $(90+(m/2))$ (the lower bound is discretionary)
$$\begin{aligned}
 \mathit{angtrasm}_{\min}&= \arccos\left({\frac{b^2 + c^2-(d-a)^2}{2bc}}\right)
\\
\mathit{angtrasm}_{\max} &= \arccos\left({\frac{b^2 + c^2-(d + a)^2}{2bc}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

My code is the following

```
% Compute transmission angle and lengths of bars
clear all

m = 32;   %rocker’s oscillation
i = 1;
f = 1;

for l = 1: (90 + m/2 );  % crank’s oscillation -pi (there is a problem here i can’t start from -20 for example)
  L(i) = l + 180 ;       %crank’s oscillation
  t = tand(L(i)/2);
  u = tand((L(i)-m)/2);
  v = tand(m/2);
  p = [1 2 -(t^2) -((t^2 + (1 + t^2))/(u^2))];
  if L(i) = = m
    fprintf('Value of crank’s oscillation is not acceptable \n' , L(l));
  else
    Q = roots(p);
    for j = 1:3
      if isreal(Q(j)) && Q(j)>0
        x = abs(t/sqrt(Q(j)));
        if x^2 > = 1 && x^2 < = u^2*t^2
          a = sqrt(v^2/(1 + v^2));
          b = sqrt(x^2*v^2/(1 + v^2));
          c = sqrt((x^2 + t^2)/(1 + t^2));
          d = sqrt((u^2 + x^2)/(1 + u^2));
          angtrasm_min(f) = acosd((b^2 + c^2-(d-a)^2)/(2*b*c));
          angtrasm_max(f) = acosd((b^2 + c^2-(d + a)^2)/(2*b*c));
          scarto_min(f) = abs(90-angtrasm_min(f));
          scarto_max(f) = abs(90-angtrasm_max(f));

          theta(f) = L(i);
          r1(f) = a;
          r2(f) = b;
          r3(f) = c;
          r4(f) = d;
          fprintf('The max transmision angle is %d when theta is %d\n',angtrasm_max(f),L(i));
          fprintf('The max transmision angle is %d when theta is %d\n',angtrasm_min(f),L(i));

          fprintf('.................................\n');
          f = f + 1;
        end
      end
    end
  end
  i = i + 1;
end
```

Comment: It is not clear what your optimization problem is. What is the variable you want to maximize/minimize? what is the variable that you are optimizing over?

Comment: I'm really sorry but i made an error copying my notes over the post. So i want to optimize the transmission's angle that is function of a,b,c,d

Comment: You can edit your question to correct the mistake

Comment: Now should be fine, i can also post one of my attempt....

Comment: But it seems that you want to find the roots of your equation and not optimize an objective function.

Comment: If you look on my code you could see the expression of angstram_max and angstram_min. By the graphic of "scarto_min" and "scarto_max" i choose the angle that optimize my problem

Comment: If I understand correctly, you solve your equation for $Q$, and create a function $\theta_\text{trans}$ that depends on $a(x), b(x), c(x), d(x)$, where $x = \sqrt{t^2/Q}$. I think that you should add all that information into your question.

Comment: Done as you recommended. Hope someone can help me

Comment: Then, you want to minimize/maximize $angtrans_{\min}$ over $L$?